# How to create slicer As Of (Up To) Date in Power BI desktop

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

In my dim_Date table I have column `MonthYear`. 
But how can I write the expression so when choosing a value, the data would be filtered **UP TO** that date, so everything from the beginning and up to that date?

For example if I select `Nov-2018`, the data should be displayed from the beginning and up to `Nov-2018`?

Thanks

[image]

UPDATE:

Cant see options "Before" or "After"

[image]

This is my dim_Date table:

```
dim_Date = ADDCOLUMNS(
    CALENDAR (DATE (2017, 1, 1), DATE (YEAR(TODAY())+1, 12, 31)),
    "DateAsInteger", FORMAT ( [Date], "YYYYMMDD" ),
    "Year", YEAR ( [Date] ),
    "MonthNumber", FORMAT ( [Date], "MM" ),
    "MonthYear", FORMAT ( [Date], "mmm-YYYY" )
)
```

Comment: You can use "Before" and "After" on Date type columns. Your `MonthYear` column is text valued. Try using putting the `Date` column on a slicer and then using "Before".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible to do with a list slicer, but the easiest option is to just use a different form of the slicer.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Alexis. I was trying to do that, but I dont have those options, probably because MonthYear is calculated column maybe? I will update in a sec

Comment: A calculated column is fine. If it's not a date type though, then you wouldn't be able to do what I suggested.